# Variable for line-wide colouring in emacs org-mode source blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, faces

What `org-mode` variable determines whether or not the `org-mode` block-background applies line wide like so:

[image]

instead of like so:

[image]

I am using the [gruvbox-dark](https://github.com/greduan/emacs-theme-gruvbox) theme.

I will attach the defface as soon as I figure out what that is (still a noob).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It‘s controlled by the `extend` attribute of face `org-block`

```
(set-face-extend 'org-block t)
```

You can find out more about face attributes in the Elisp manual. Evaluate the following expression in Emacs:

```
(info "(elisp)Face Attributes")
```

or, equivalently, `C-h i g(elisp)Face Attributes`.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.
Can you suggest some place where I can learn more about face attributes in general?

Comment: @ArjunGhosh the manual: (info "(elisp)Face Attributes")

Comment: Thanks again! I didn't know I could access the docs like that. I thought it was just describe funtion and the like. Rn its telling me there's no such thing as elisp, but I can google my way from here!